# How does management IP of Router get assigned?

Tags: router

When I try to access router's GUI, it is very common to go to **192.168.1.1**. The term for this is **management ip address**. My questions are

- If router is in bridge mode, what happen to this IP Address?
- If router is not in bridge mode, and is behaving as DHCP client, will this IP be automatically change?
- Router have **interfaces**, is this IP address map to one of the interfaces? If so, how does the router decide which interface it will use as its management ip address?

Comment: It's configured in the router configuration screens.

Comment: Hi thank you, we can freely assign it to any kind of ip address? like 123.123.123.123?

Comment: @Zanko No, You can’t.

Comment: It's needs to be an address that is valid on your network.

Comment: Does the ip address live on any interface of the router? I believe that each interface on router have corresponding ip address

Comment: @Zanko No; It doesn’t

Comment: @Ramhound why it deosnt? And why i cant?

Comment: Are you talking about wifi bridge mode? Or something like PPPoE which is sometimes called bridge mode on modems.

Comment: It doesn’t work the way you have described.

Comment: @jdwolf PPPoE Sorry for being unclear

Answer (score 1):

When you have a new router, the factory preset gives the router a means to access this router. Although it is fairly common to be 192.168.0.1, there are other possibilities too. The router often comes with a sticker that tells you what the default address is and it is also mentioned in the manual that came with the router.

If you no longer have the manual, you can search for that on the internet too.

Some routers add a DNS entry to allow you to access the router that way, such as http://myrouter to connect to your router instead of using the ip address, but it has an ipaddress nevertheless.

Once you are in the router, you can change the ipaddress. Although you can make this any ip address you want, if you misconfigure this, it is likely that you will lose access to the router and it may also be impossible to reach the router in any way. A reset to factory defaults is then the only way to get back into the router, but also, you will then need to reprogram your router.

By default, most routers will setup a DHCP server for you. This means that any device connected to the router, will automatically get an ipaddress in its range. Although you could therefor setup 123.45.67.89 as the ip address of the router, and make the DHCP server setup other ip addresses in the range of 123.45.67.0-123.45.67.88, it is a really bad idea to do this.

Given that it has been established that LAN networks should be in either 10.x.x.x , 172.x.x.x, 169.254.x.x or 192.168.x.x. Any other range will overlap with what's available on the internet and will cause you to not be able to access some online services as ip addresses overlap. You request a website, the ipaddress appears to be in the range of your lan, and instead of your request going out into the internet, your router keeps it inside your network, and you get a page not found, or similar error.

Note, I mentioned 169.254.x.x range too. This range is reserved for when no DHCP server is in the network to work with a cross-over lan cable. You should not setup your network to be in this range either, but it is a range dedicated for LAN networks, so I had to mention it.

When you configure your router, you usually give it a static ip address, but some devices allow for its ip address to be asigned by a DHCP server, although I have not seen consumer routers that offer this function. In the case of this being utilized, these devices usually have another means to access the device, such as a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) such as http://myrouter or a program that will find any of its devices automatically in range of your network.

A router in bridge mode does not change. All it does is forward everything from the WAN port to the first LAN port. This is usually the case for modem/router combinations.

It is up to the device if it changes its ip address upon being in bridge mode.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I understand alot now. Though I have one question. During bridge mode the router become just a dumb switch right? For example `ISP -> IP  A -> Router -> IP A -> Switch -> IPA -> Computer`. If this is the case, is it still possible  to access router static address (GUI)?

Comment: Yes, you can still access the GUI if you know the IP address, but the router part will be disabled. If the router has no settings to display, it may only show a static message, or the option to switch it back to unbridged mode, depending on how much control you have over it being in bridged mode. For example, an ISP modem that is set in bridged by the ISP can still configure some settings related to it being a modem, but things like wifi usually are disabled and cannot be configured.

Comment: Hi when you say I can access the gui, lets say the IP address is 192.168.1.1, how can I reach that network when the modem is bridged? The only IP exposed will be the ISP ip right?

Comment: Find out what its ip address is and type it into your browser. You can scan for it, or google the internet for what it is supposed to be.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I meant to say, how can my browser technically access 192.168.1.1 when the only IP exposed to me is ISP ip through bridged mode.

Comment: Just enter it in your browser, in many cases the router understands it and it works. If not, then you would need to give your own pc a static ip address in its range.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer this question as it applies to standards and best practice considering the fact that some networking devices don't follow standards and are buggy.

Generally routers will have configuration applied to each interface. That is the LAN interface (switch or virtual interface across several switches) and the WAN interface (usually one port).

The LAN interface is usually configured with a static ip and subnet and the WAN interface is configured with either a DHCP client where the modem device provides a DHCP server or a bridge protocol like PPPoE or just PPP. This means the modem is not providing any routing function. (note this includes routers with built in DSL modems where using PPP would mean the WAN side of the router would not provide any routing function as well as the combination of a routing device that is connected over Ethernet to a modem which would use PPPoE).

So given your questions if the router/modem is in bridged mode meaning it uses one of those two protocols PPP or PPPoE then nothing happens to the LAN side IP address unless the LAN side IP address is not static and is delegated by the WAN side ip address. IPv6 addresses may use delegated prefixes for example. IPv4 may use a subnet of the wan IP for example.

To your second question on most routers on ipv4 no they will not unless they are using a subnet of the WAN (almost no home router will even have an option for this). On IPv6 yes and no. On IPv6 ULA prefixed addresses will not change while delegated addresses will. Depending on your router clients might get both types of addresses. It's also possible the delegated addresses are not based on the ISP or WAN side address.

To your last question: If the WAN is a DHCP client its set to the address the ISP gives. Further if your router is configured to delegate its addresses then it will use a subset of the ISPs address or a delegated prefix on IPv6. When the WAN side is bridged there is no set IP address on the interface so there's nothing to delegate no matter how the LAN side is configured.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am still confuse how this statement `So given your questions if the router/modem is in bridged mode meaning it uses one of those two protocols PPP or PPPoE then nothing happens to the LAN side IP address unless the LAN side IP address is not static and is delegated by the WAN side ip address.`. For the bridge to work properly LAN **MUST HAVE** exactly the same IP as WAN side (from ISP) right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that by "router" you mean the more-or-less standard consumer-grade devices that are commonly used in households for ADSL or cable access.

It is important to understand the difference between the outside-world and the inside-world. In the outside world, the IP addresses are global. In the inside world, your IP addresses are local (typically 192.168.x.x). The router sits in between. You can see the outside-address if your router be browsing to one of the "what's my IP"-sites. You will see that this address differs from the address that you get with ifconfig (Linux, unix etc.) or ipconfig (Windows) on your host.

When you put your router in bridge-mode, the distinction between the inside and outside disappears. So your inside gets connected to the outside and you will need to use the outside IP address on your PC/tablet/etc.

If the router behaves as a DHCP client, it is in general for the outside world, not for the inside. It means that your router gets its IP address from your Internet provider over DHCP. This is the address you see on the "what's my IP" sites.

As for the interfaces on the router, you need to understand that these devices are in fact a router+switch. In general, the router is between the "WAN"-port and the switch, and all the LAN-ports are on the switch. In your case, the 192.168.1.1 lives on the LAN-side of the router (which is on the same switch as the LAN-ports), but the address is not the address of one of the switch-ports.

In a default set-up, the router-address on the LAN-side would be 192.168.1.1. This address is only reachable from the LAN-side. The WAN-side would be a DHCP-address that the ISP provides.

Comment: Thanks! If my router is DHCP client i will receive ISP ip address for example 172.123.123.123 for my router. However, if it is not a DHCP client, then what am I receiving from the ISP?

Comment: After thinking about it, it impossible not to be a client because ISP is probably running DHCP server?

Comment: In general, ISP's run DHCP-servers. In some cases, you get a fixed IP address. But that depends a bit on your ISP. Even if you have a fixed IP address your ISP still may run a DHCP-server.